# should i replace the tires/tubes to sell vintage bicycle?

Tags: tire, vintage

new to this site.  I have a vintage GT Pro Performer from my youth, all original and am considering selling it.  The tires are original but would fall apart if someone tried to ride it.  Is it worth replacing the tires/tubes with new ones to get more money when i go to sell it.  Trying to figure out if I should just leave it alone and let the next owner worry about it or if it would add value to the sell greater than the price of the tires?
thanks...

Comment: I am posting as a comment because I don't know if there is a definitive answer. I would purchase some inexpensive tires and tubes. Leave the original tires on it to validate the originality of the bike. Offer the potential buyer the new tires and  tubes installed if they prefer.

Comment: Also a comment because it lacks evidence, but in my experience there are very few replacements/upgrades you can so that will make you back the money+time spent on them.

Comment: We can't really help you with selling it.  Perhaps consider riding it again, or hand it off to a younger family member who will enjoy it like you did.

Comment: It depends on whether it's sold as collectors' item or usable bike. When I was in BMX buying age, I would definitely have picked a bike I could ride right away instead of buying tires. Now I just wouldn't buy a second hand bike I can't test ride.

Answer (score 6):

If it's really vintage (collectible) and has value for being vintage and the tires are original, don't change them.

When people buy vintage (collectible) thing, they want everything vintage, even if not immediately usable; if you change anything thing, it will loose value (as a collectible object)

The best thing would be for you to find good working order original tires.

Comment: thank you for the info.  i guess i will just clean it up and leave it alone.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when we're talking about bikes from 15+ years, you most likely won't get the money back which you put into it. Also many people buying vintage bikes are either collectors or hobbyists who prefer all original as Max pointed out, or they'll want to restore the bike and pick the tires themselves (picking parts for projects is part of the fun).

I would sell it as is, just clean it up and take good pics (the first pic should always be side-on from the drivetrain side).